# Call function from different class and namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm having some trouble to call a function from a namespaced class in a different namespaced class. In the dummy example below I would like to know how to use Class2 within Class1. I'm getting the error:

> Trait 'name1\name2\Class2' not found in class1.php

The code:

```
#file index.php

require "class1.php";
require "class2.php";
$class1 = new name1\Class1();
$class1->sayHello();

#file class1.php

namespace name1{
    class Class1{
        use name2\Class2;
        public function sayHello(){
            echo Class2::staticFunction();
        }
    }
}

#file class2.php

namespace name2{
    class Class2{
        public static function staticFunction(){
            return "hello!";
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You have syntax error: not `public static staticFunction()` but `public static function staticFunction()`

Comment: Also in index.php: not just `sayHello();` but `$class1->sayHello();`

Comment: Yes @zavg thanks :) , as I commented in other posts, the errors were present because it's not the actual code. It was just a (really bad written :( ) dummy example. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you've got several errors which I have fixed.
Here's the working code you need:

```
# index.php
include "class1.php";
include "class2.php";
$class1 = new name1\Class1();
$class1->sayHello();

# class1.php
namespace name1;
use name2\Class2;
class Class1{
    public function sayHello(){
        echo Class2::staticFunction();
    }
}

# class2.php
namespace name2;
class Class2{
    public static function staticFunction(){
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

Some explanations:

- When in class definition the `use` is used for using `traits` and not `namespace`
- In PHP `namespace` need not be enclosed in curly brackets
- In PHP you include files with `include`, `include_once`, `require`, or `require_once`, and not `import`

Comment: The errors were present because it's not the actual code. It was just a (really bad written :( ) dummy example. I accept the answer. Thank you!!!

Comment: cool, I added some more explanations which I hope will help you better understand what's going on :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your first class, your trait is calling class2 as `use name2\Class2` but, you are still within the `name1{}` namespace, so in reality you are calling it as: `use name1\name2\Class2`

So, you need to change

`use name2\Class2;` to `use \name2\Class2`

Try this.

```
namespace name1{
  use \name2\Class2;
    class Class1{
        public function sayHello(){
            echo Class2::staticFunction();
        }
    }
}

#file class2.php

namespace name2{
    class Class2{
        public static staticFunction(){
            return "hello!";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, another tip: If you are separating your classes in separate files, you do not need to separate them as in they way you have done. Just call the namespace simple as:

```
// file1.php
namespace person; 
class name{}

//file2.php 
namespace address; 
class name{}
```

Comment: Hi @sam_io thanks for the response, that is not working either, I'm getting:

PHP Fatal error:  name1\Class1 cannot use name2\Class2 - it is not a trait

Comment: Please remove the `use \name2\Class2` outside the class. @albertogarrido check my example again. Only traits can be called inside a class.

Comment: By taking out the "use" statement I get: Call to undefined function sayHello()

Comment: @albertogarrido you should call the function as `$class1->sayHello();`

Comment: Too many hours today :( 
The errors were present because it's not the actual code. It was just a (really bad written :( ) dummy example. I will vote up this solution as soon as I can. The actual working solution was use name2\Class2 outside of the class. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not drop the static method and just inject the class? Seems like going through extra work for something so simple. That's what function arguments are made for.

```
namespace name1{
  use \name2\Class2;
    class Class1{
        public function sayHello($Class2){
            echo $Class2->someFunction();
        }
    }
}

namespace name2{
    class Class2{
        public function someFunction(){
            return "hello!";
        }
    }
}

#index.php
include "class1.php";
include "class2.php";
$Class1 = new name1\Class1();
$Class2 = new name2\Class2();
$Class1->sayHello($Class2);
//hello!
```

Comment: Thanks @Tek but it's a dummy example, on the actual code has to be static function. Anyway for the doubt it's not relevant.